# Spark Streaming Delayed write to sink

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to introduce a delay of 1 hr before I write to a streaming sink (i.e eventhub). How can this be achieved?
I tried the following:

```
sinkOutput
 .withColumn("Timestamp", current_timestamp())
 .withWatermark("Timestamp", "60 minutes")
 .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("60 minutes"))
 .format("org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider")
 .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
 .options(ehConf.toMap) // EventHubsConf containing the destination EventHub connection string.
 .start()
```

But it does not seem to be working. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: this seems becoming batch job requiremtn rather streaming type job

Comment: What is our input source? If you are reading from a streaming source like Kafka and your requirement is to write data into eventhub every one hour then `.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("60 minutes"))` will create a micro batch every one hour and will write it to source. You can also try to implement custom sink like `foreachBatch` where you can define the logic and introduce wait time

Comment: Yes my input source is eventhub which is another streaming source like kafka. In my case, there is no windowing logic present. I just want to delay every row from its timestamp by 60 mins.

for example: Data with 01:00 timestamp should be written at 02:00, 01:07 at 02:07, 01:15: at 02:15 and so on